# Rails render and return in before_action, DoubleRenderError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, before-filter

In a controller action with a before_action, using `render something and return` does not actually cause the controller to stop executing the rest of the action. In my testing, only when called in the controller action does `and return` work as I would expect.

```
# DoubleRenderError
class SomeController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :double_render, only: [:index]

    def index
        render file: "public/500.html", status: :internal_server_error
    end

    def double_render
        render file: "public/404.html", status: :not_found and return
    end
end

# Renders 404 only, no error
class SomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
        render file: "public/404.html", status: :not_found and return
        render file: "public/500.html", status: :internal_server_error
    end
end
```

What's going on here? Can before_actions stop the rest of a controller's execution?

Comment: rendering/redirecting in a before filter has stopped the action since about rails 2.0 - your index method shouldn't be called

Comment: Are you seeing the same behavior I do with my example code?

Comment: I've definitely got before filters that redirect as a way of ending the action

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your intention is to render the 404 page, you shouldn't render it manually in the before_filter. The right way of doing that is raising a routing error, like this:

`raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')`

You could implement a method called "render_404", raise this exception in it and let the routing system do the rest.

EDIT: Actually, your code should work. I really don't know what is going on. I wrote the same thing here and it worked - the action method is never called if the before_filter renders something. What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using rails 4.1.4.

Comment: What if I want to render a json in a before filter with a custom error message? (I am using my controller as API provider for an app)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple case of flow control.

Yes, when you `and return` from *within* the method, it obviously returns and doesn't reach the second render.

Nothing about rendering inside a `before_filter` is meant to stop the actual invocation of the action itself, and calling `and return` from a `before_filter` doesn't affect the execution of a completely separate method invocation.

This is pure Ruby flow-control, no Rails magic involved.

Comment: I suspected as much. Understanding what I'm trying to accomplish, can you please provide some direction?

Comment: See the other answer. Raise an exception rather than rendering an error.